# remove quotes from json_encode keys

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I am new to jquery and I am trying to use Jquery UI to create an auto-complete.I'm still learning so I'm sure my code could be a lot better but this is just a start.
I am having a problem where jquery is putting quotes around the json keys.I've had a look though stackoverflow and I can't seem to find a solution so I thought it's worth asking as I am well and truly stuck.I think it must be something wrong with my php somewhere.

```
{"value":"Managerial Accountants","id":"5929"}
```

I want my output to come out like this"

```
{value:"Managerial Accountants",id:"5929"}
```

This is the rest of my code:

```
 <script>
 jQuery(function(){
 jQuery(function () {
   var checkboxval;
   var availableTags = [
 <?php
// Database Connection
 error_reporting(-1);
 ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

 $con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

 $q="SELECT name as value,term_id as id FROM 7terms WHERE term_id not in 
     (select   parent from 7term_taxonomy) and term_id in (select term_id from   
     7term_taxonomy where  taxonomy='cat')";

$r = mysqli_query($con, $q);            

$city_state = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){


 $rows[]=$row;
}
$json = json_encode($rows,true);
echo $json;
 ?>

];

//set autocomplete search
set_autocomplete_search("tags");
set_autocomplete_search("tags1");
set_autocomplete_search("tags2");

function set_autocomplete_search(p_tags) {
    var temp_p_tags = "#" + p_tags;
    jQuery(temp_p_tags).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var txtbx1 = (ui.item.name);
            var catid = (ui.item.id);
            alert(catid);
            jQuery(temp_p_tags).val(txtbx1);
            var tags = jQuery(temp_p_tags).val(txtbx1);
            //var checkboxval = "";
            checkboxval = tags.val();




            jQuery("#" + checkboxval + "").prop("checked", true);



        },
        change: function () {
            //alert("changed detected");
            //$("#" + checkboxval + "").prop("checked", false);
        }
    }).blur(function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();

            //uncheck all checkboxes first
            jQuery(".test input:checked").each(function() {
                jQuery(this).attr("checked", false);
            });

            //set checkbox
            var checkbox_tags = jQuery("#tags").val();
            jQuery("#" + checkbox_tags + "").prop("checked", true);

            var checkbox_tags1 = jQuery("#tags1").val();
            jQuery("#" + checkbox_tags1 + "").prop("checked", true);

            var checkbox_tags2 = jQuery("#tags2").val();
            jQuery("#" + checkbox_tags2).prop("checked", true);
        });
   }
 });
});//]]>
```

Thanks for your time.I really appreciate any help I can get with this as I still have a lot to learn and have been stuck on this for a couple of days.

Comment: There is nothing wrong, things are supposed to be this way because that's how JSON is. If you want the output to look like something else then you are trying to solve a problem (which you don't mention) in a completely unsuitable manner.

Comment: Your desired output is not valid JSON. If for some reason you need your output in that **exact** format, you'll need to create it using your own function.

Comment: The reason I need to it come out in that format is because the auto-complete doesn't work if there are quotes around the keys.So,then there must be something wrong with my jquery script?

Comment: @LaurieWilliams: How do you know that? Did you remove the quotes and saw it working afterwards?

Comment: @jon.Yes.I put in some hardcoded values in like this: avalibaletags[{value:"Managerial Accountants",id:"5929"}] and the auto-complete worked.But as soon as I had quotes around the keys it stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing this issue because you are not using json correctly.

You can still just echo the `json_encode()` into the JS variable but get rid of the `[]` brackets and then use `.parseJSON()` to get what you need:

```
var availableTags = $.parseJSON('<?php
    // Database Connection
    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

    $con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

    $q="SELECT name as value,term_id as id FROM 7terms WHERE term_id not in 
         (select   parent from 7term_taxonomy) and term_id in (select term_id from   
         7term_taxonomy where  taxonomy='cat')";

    $r = mysqli_query($con, $q);            

    $city_state = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))
    {
        $rows[]=$row;
    }
    echo json_encode($rows,true);
?>');
```

This solution should get you going but I would recommend opting for an AJAX based solution where your query is in a PHP file and call upon it with AJAX because **[$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)** can auto-convert a JSON string into the properly formatted array/object expected as long as you set `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: This is right.Thanks,I was getting double square brackets so there was nothing wrong with the json.Thank you so much @MonkeyZeus